# OpenCL execute kernel wrile copying data to CPU

Tags: opencl, gpu

I am learning with OpenCL and I have heard, that there is possibility co compute on GPU and copy data at once. I have taks like this:

```
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(ker, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(1024*1024));
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buff, true, 0, 1024*1024, &buffer[0]);
```

Am I able to somehow execute there operations at once? To copy first results back to CPU while executing kernels with higher indices?

I would like to do something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<1024; ++i){
    queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(ker, cl::Range(i*1024), cl::NDRange(1024));
    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buff, true, i*1024, 1024, &buffer[i*1024]);
}
```

But to execute kernels and reads asynchronously. Is something like this possible? Are two queues and kernel completing events correct solution?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using separate command queues for upload, compute, and download (and events to synchronize!) is the correct way to overlap copy and compute. On some pro-level hardware you can even overlap upload and download because they have two DMA engines.

Answer (score 1):

If you read though [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/) you'll see you can answer your own question.  In particular, look at the 'cl_event' parameter to several OpenCL functions.

Also if you look carefully at your own code you'll see you set the blocking parameter to `true` (which should really be `CL_TRUE` if you want to block, though maybe that's handled by your queue object?).  You'll want to change that and use events instead, and use the necessary `clFlush()` between getting an event and making use of it in an event list.

Finally, assuming you're executing the kernel multiple times with new data each time, you can queue up multiple instances of the kernel, though this necessitates holding more data in memory on the device, so you may need to be careful you don't run out of memory.

Edit:  If you are queuing up multiple instances, you will want to use either `CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE` or multiple command queues (or even both).  I find the former easier to use with proper event usage, but it really comes down to personal preference.